# UnityException: Tag: is not defined

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags

I'm following the [Unity Roll A Ball Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) but I'm having an issue picking up the spinning objects. Whenever I roll over them I get this error:

> UnityException: Tag: PickUp is not defined.
>   PlayerController.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:30)

I've made sure my tag `PickUp` is exactly the same as in the code, and still it doesn't work. I've been trying to fix this for a long some so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code in your `PlayerController` script and a screenshot of a game object with the `PickUp` tag? In the code on the tutorial you linked, the tag they used was `Pick Up` not `PickUp` (notice the space). If you copied the code in the `PlayerController` from the tutorial then you will get this error because the tags don't match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add the tag(`PickUp`) from the Editor before you can reference it from script.

[image]

Comment: I love this answer. What software did you use to record the gif?

Comment: @LewsTherin I use LICEcap v1.26 for this. It's a nifty software.

Comment: @Programmer I think I've done that, but I still get the same error. My player sphere has one tag and that's pickup? Do I need another one? Or do I need to create the tag then write the code?

Comment: Make sure to spell it correctly. It is case sensitive. What tag error are you getting now?

Comment: @Programmer Ok I'm probably just being thick right now but all I did was check that I have my tag added (it is btw the same as in the code caps and everything). Sorry :3

Comment: Good. That's all you have to do when you see tag exception error. Don't forget to accept answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: You are welcome and here is how to accept answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: plus one for gif answer :D

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for your help :) But it still isn't working? Is their a chance I might have an issue with something else?

Comment: I though you said you got it working? You are still getting the-same error? You shouldn't if you followed what I did in the animated gif....

Comment: @Programmer No that was a different user who said it was working, well, I appreciate your help, thanks! Do you by any chance know where I can download the roll a ball project from someone so I can see what they did to get it working?

Comment: @iFallOffStuff This answer was to solve your question about the tag error you are getting.Since I asked **twice** for the current error you are getting and you refused to say, I think that you are **no** longer getting that error which is why I posted this. Your problem in this question is solved.  Anyways, as for the project, follow that tutorial from start to finish. That's how you learn. If you can't get anything to work then you missed a step. Re-watch the video. If you have a particular question, you can create a new question and tell us what the problem is. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

I was following a text tutorial and I copied the tag name and pasted it into Unity instead of writing it myself, and I'm assuming it has copied an extra space by itself. (I'm assuming)

And I'm assuming this is why it couldn't find the tag even though everything seemed to be matching.

I deleted the tag name and this time wrote it myself, and it everything worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).